# ag-grid : how to select the value from dropdown in ag-grid

Tags: angular, angular8, ag-grid

It was really difficult to for the title of this question, let be someone can help me forming it better later.

Here is the complete scenario

1. I have a editable ag-grid with first column as dropdown.
2. drop-down is filled with some value, has the corresponding key for it. so when you select any value, and try to read the data it will give you key.
3. This grid has some data which is coming from backend. so as the first column is dropdown, some data is also coming for it.
4. the data which i am getting from backend in grid has a corresponding key in the dropdown.

problem : so when I am trying to read the grid data without changing the dropdown, it is giving me the data which is visible on UI and not the corresponding key. but when I change the value in drop-down and then try to read the data from grid then it is giving me corresponding key.

what i want to implement : if I read the data from grid, it should return the key.

html code:

```
<ag-grid-angular #agGrid style="width: 100%; height: 500px;" class="ag-theme-alpine"
            [rowData]="rows | filterTable" [columnDefs]="columns" (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)">
```

ts code :

```
            cellEditor: 'agSelectCellEditor',
            cellEditorParams: {
              values: this.extractValues(this.fieldMap)
            },
            valueFormatter: function (params) {
              if (response.fieldMap[params.value] == null) {
                for (var key in response.fieldMap) {
                  if (response.fieldMap.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    if (name === response.fieldMap[key]) {
                      return key;
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
              return response.fieldMap[params.value];
            },
            valueParser: function (params) {
              console.log('value parser');
              for (var key in this.fieldMap) {
                if (this.fieldMap.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                  if (name === this.fieldMap[key]) {
                    return key;
                  }
                }
              }
            },
```

Comment: what do you mean by _if I read the data from grid_?

Comment: api.forEachNode(function(rowNode, index) {
    console.log('node ' + rowNode.data.athlete + ' is in the grid');
});

Comment: Please create a full example of your problem on Plunker or Stackblitz.